# Is there a Drupal module that allows content edits to be "rolled back" like Stack Exchange does?

Tags: drupal

Looking for a way to roll back edits to text edits in the body of nodes/pages in Drupal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps required, as far as I know, anyway. Setting options for new nodes, and configuring permissions to make the revisions visible.

#### Default Node Options

Log on to your Drupal installation and go to *Administer*, *Content Management* and *Content Types*.

Select a content type (say, **Page**) and press *edit*.

Look for the heading *Workflow Settings* and set the default options for this content type. Turn *on* "Create New Revision".

#### Permission settings

Go to *Administer*, *User Management* and *Permissions*.

Under "Node Module" look for these permissions:

- View revisions
- Revert revisions
- Delete revisions

Hope this helps.

Comment: After you've done all of the above, create new page; if you've already have an existing page, see the next step. Now browser to the page, you'll see the following tabs: View, Edit, <other tabs depending on modules you have installed>. Click edit, and make a minor edit to the page, then go to "Revision information" expand the options and make sure that "Create new revision" is selected by default. Click SAVE. Then look at the tabs again, a tab named "Revisions" is now next to the other tabs, those being: View, Edit, Revisions, <other tabs>.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Drupal makes it possible to store your edits to a node as a new revision instead of overwriting the original. You can enhance that functionality with extra modules like [Diff](http://drupal.org/project/diff).

Comment: Thanks, how do I enable/view the default revisions, I've looked high and low and can't find them. See something about adding a comment to an edit, but no way to view, or back to an previous edit/state. Thanks!

Comment: So, Diff rocks, but @Bevan answer allowed me to get to the point where I could make revisions to see the diff(s). Your answer likely lead to @Bevan posting an answer though, and I would like to give you more points. Just comment 2 or 3 more times, and I'll +1 each comment. Again, thank you!!

Comment: Thanks Blunders, I really appreciate your upvotes and accepted answers. However, while points are nice, what matters to me most is that we helped you achieve your goal. Bevan did a great job explaining the basic steps, he deserves the accepted answer here.